# Core data Int16 as optional

Tags: swift, core-data, option-type

1. In Swift, how do you make an `NSManaged Int16` property be `optional` like this:

   `NSManaged var durationType: Int16?`

   I'm getting compiler error: `roperty cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`
2. If this is not possible, and I check the `optional` box in the Core Data model editor, how do I then check if this property has a value when coming from the database?

Answer (score 4):

You can make the property optional and keep it `Int16`. The key is that `@NSManaged` is not required, but if you remove it, you **must** implement your own accessor methods.

One possible implementation:

```
var durationType: Int16?
    {
    get {
        self.willAccessValueForKey("durationType")
        let value = self.primitiveValueForKey("durationType") as? Int
        self.didAccessValueForKey("durationType")

        return (value != nil) ? Int16(value!) : nil
    }
    set {
        self.willChangeValueForKey("durationType")

        let value : Int? = (newValue != nil) ? Int(newValue!) : nil
        self.setPrimitiveValue(value, forKey: "durationType")

        self.didChangeValueForKey("durationType")
    }
}
```

Comment: One *could* replace the conditional expressions by `return map(value) { Int16($0) }` and `let value = map(newValue) { Int($0) }`. Perhaps a matter of taste, but avoids the need to use the forced-unwrapping operator.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This means implementing accessors for many properties in the data model, which is writing a lot of code. If I still want to use @NSManaged, is there way to check if Core Data stored NULL for the property?

Comment: You would check for nil with the same `primitiveValueForKey` call used above. The `get` accessor above just loads the value and checks it for nil, and you can do the same thing in other places if you want.